# iOS notifications sporadic (FMX)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

Following the Embarcadero docs [at this link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Notifications_(iOS_and_Android)) i'm testing notifications on iOS (in FMX app built with C++).  I've done the follownig:

- Added `#include <System.Notification.hpp>` to the header file
- Set `FMLocalNotificationPermission` to `true`
- Dropped `TNotificationCenter` component on the form

Then, i put the following code in a button click:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ScheduleNotificationClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (NotificationCenter1->Supported()) {
            TNotification *myNotification = NotificationCenter1->CreateNotification();
            __try {
                    myNotification->Name = "MyNotification";
                    myNotification->AlertBody = "C++ for your mobile device is here!";
                    // Fire in 10 seconds
                    myNotification->FireDate = Now() + EncodeTime(0, 0, 10, 0);
                    // Send notification to the notification center
                    NotificationCenter1->ScheduleNotification(myNotification);
            }
            __finally {
                    myNotification->DisposeOf();
            }
    }
}
```

Once in a while it works...but rarely and never more than once.  Most of the time it doesn't at all (repeated deleting and reinstall of app).

Next, i tried the "Present the Notification Message Immediately" code they provide:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::PresentNotificationClick(TObject *Sender)
{
if (NotificationCenter1->Supported()) {
       TNotification *myNotification = NotificationCenter1->CreateNotification();
       __try { 
               myNotification->Name = "MyNotification";
               myNotification->AlertBody = "C++ for your mobile device is here!";
               // Set Icon Badge Number (for iOS) or message number (for Android) as well
               myNotification->Number = 18;
               myNotification->EnableSound = False;
               // Send notification to the notification center
               NotificationCenter1->PresentNotification(myNotification);
      }
      __finally {  
               myNotification->DisposeOf();
      }
 }
}
```

Nothing happens at all with this code.  I've tried this from scratch several times and i'm as sure as i can be that i'm coding it per their examples.  I'm using 10.3 (Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.3 Version 26.0.32429.4364).  I would think my code has a problem except once in blue moon it works.

My target is iPhone running 12.1.4 and i've tried building with SDK11.4 and SDK12.0, no difference.  When i first run app i get the "allow or don't allow" popup and my app subsequently shows up in the Notification settings - just doesn't work.

russ

**UPDATE 3-25-2019**:  If I run that top block of code (from a button click on iPhone) it will now run everytime - but ONLY IF i immediately kill the app after clicking.  10 seconds later it fires the notification.  Why won't the notification appear if i leave my app running??

Comment: I use notifications with similar code and have not experienced problems. However, the difference is that I use notifications to remind user to use the app, i.e. only when app is not running. I remove all notifications in TApplicationEvent.BecameActive and add all notifications in TApplicationEvent.EnteredBackground

Comment: You should NOT be disposing of the object that you schedule. Embarcadero's example is wrong in that regard. Get rid of the `try..finally` altogether and let ARC manage the object lifetime for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are calling "PresentNotificationClick" from the TButton when you click it?

Comment: Yes, i stuck a ShowMessage in there to be certain.

Comment: What's interesting is for my code, when I call the Specific Procedure UANotification I don't use the  myNotification->FireDate = Now()  (Keep in mind I'm doing it in Delphi, not in C++), mabye you could try something like this : https://imgur.com/a/ciYYwby

Comment: Thanks Relinkvent, i tried your suggestion.  Still no dice.