# iOS delayed notification only fires if app closed (FMX)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

Based on this Embarcadero [example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Notifications_(iOS_and_Android)) I have the following code in a TButton click in FMX app for iOS.  Supposed to pop up a notification after 10 seconds.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ScheduleNotificationButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
if (NotificationCenter1->Supported()) {
        TNotification *myNotification = NotificationCenter1->CreateNotification();
        __try {
                myNotification->Name = "MyNotification";
                myNotification->AlertBody = "C++ for your mobile device is here!";
                // Fire in 10 seconds
                myNotification->FireDate = Now() + EncodeTime(0, 0, 10, 0);
                // Send notification to the notification center
                NotificationCenter1->ScheduleNotification(myNotification);
        }
        __finally {
                myNotification->DisposeOf();
        }
  }
}
```

When i click the button nothing happens.  But, I accidentally figured out that i can make it fire by closing the app AFTER clicking the button.  If i click the button and then close the app, sure enough, at 10 seconds the notification pops up.  **What could possibly** be suppressing the notification from firing while the app is running?

p.s.  This is related to my earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895344/ios-notifications-sporadic-fmx/55005511?noredirect=1#comment96787676_55005511) but this is unique enough i thought clearer to make separate post.

Comment: You should NOT be disposing of the object that you schedule. Embarcadero's example is wrong in that regard. Get rid of the `try..finally` altogether and let ARC manage the object lifetime for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - that solved it.  Thanks!